# How to store edges in an ordered way in OrientDB with pyorient

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

I want to store edges in an ordered way using the `pyorient` API.

According to an outdated [API page](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Graph-Blueprints.html), there are a few examples using the Java API, e.g.

```
person.createEdgeProperty(Direction.OUT, "Photos").setOrdered(true);
```

And equivalently in SQL:

```
orientdb> CREATE PROPERTY out_Photos LINKLIST
orientdb> ALTER PROPERTY User.out_Photos CUSTOM ORDERED=TRUE
```

I would like to do the same thing using `pyorient` but none of the documentation I've seen even hints that this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way to do it, possibly the only way, is to use the `command` function to issue SQL queries.

For edges that already exist, this requires deleting all the edges first, then creating the LINKLIST edge property (see code below):

```
client.command("""
    CREATE PROPERTY Project.in_WorkedOn LINKLIST
    ALTER PROPERTY Project.in_WorkedOn CUSTOM ORDERED=TRUE
""")
```

And then adding all the edges back. By default the ordering will be based on edge creation order.

To set the ordering, do something like so:

```
client.command("""
    UPDATE #120:1 SET in_WorkedOn = [#228:4, #229:2, #228:3, #229:3]
""")
```